# Open a webview in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to open a webpage by using WebWiew, url starts with "http://" and it has no "https://" (I am not good at this point)

below is my code;

xml file

```
  // ...
  <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 //...
```

in fragment;

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
    webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    webView.settings.databasePath = ""

//  webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
    webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

    val url: String = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    webView.loadUrl(url)

}
```

Unfortunately the page is opening like this;

[image]

I have added in manifest file;

```
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Moreover I also tried

```
 android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

where network_security_config.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">www.xxx.com</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Lastly I have also tried [AdvancedWebView](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) but result is the same

Comment: It seems like you should enable javascript.

Comment: I have enabled it by "webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true"

Comment: Try to enable cache then: `webView.settings.appCacheEnabled = true`

Answer (score 0):

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: I wrote it in Kotlin, "webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true"